# How can I replace or style the scrollbar of the Twitter Embedded Timeline widget?

Tags: twitter, widget, scrollbar

I have read up on all the customization options noted here:
https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines
(e.g., "noscrollbar" to hide it altogether)

I want a scrollbar, but not the ugly one included with the default widget.

I either want to override the style of the default scrollbar or I want to use my own scrollbar to send scroll event to the embedded timeline.